# Print contents of pdf file to console

Tags: java, java-7, pdfbox

I am re-implementing a subset of pdftk (pdftk fails with newer versions of pdf) and one of it's features it the ability to output an interactive pdf file to the command line (for piping purposes). I currently am doing that with

```
if("".equals(output)){
        File tmp=new File("tmp.pdf");
        doc.save(tmp);
        output= new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("tmp.pdf")), "UTF-8");
        tmp.delete();
}
System.out.println(output);
```

The problem is when I pipe this to out.pdf. and open it, only the form fields are in the new pdf field. My first thought would be that the second line would be the faulty one, but tmp.pdf is the full pdf file, suggesting that the problem is in the line where I am reading the pdf. Any suggestions?

Edit:
I found a different way that mostly works using /dev/nul or CON (os dependent). This way is better as it doesn't create temp files, but on windows it doesn't pipe correctly. Any ways to make it pipe?

```
if("".equals(output)){
    if("W".equals(System.getProperty("os.name").substring(0,1)))
        doc.save(new File("CON"));
    else
        doc.save(new File("/dev/stdout"));
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: 1) How is this related to PDFBox? 2) In the third line, you're saving something (what?) to tmp.pdf. Then you're reading some binary data into a String. Very weird.

Comment: The third line saves doc (a PDDocument from pdfbox) to the file. I would just turn the file to a string, but pdfbox doesn't have a good way of reading the file as a string that I've found.

Comment: I am now using a different solution:
if("W".equals(System.getProperty("os.name").substring(0,1)))
    doc.save(new File("CON"));
else
    doc.save(new File("/dev/stdout"));
which mostly works. The only problem with this version is that I can't pipe the output in windows.

Comment: How about reading to a byte array, and then using System.out.write() ?

Comment: the newer version is better as it doesn't create temp files. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: PDFBox can save to a stream, so you could try doc.save(System.out). Although I've never tested whether System.out can be used for such a purpose and keep the bytes intact.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments - instead of saving to a temp file, you can save to System.out:

```
doc.save(System.out);
```

Although I've never tested whether System.out can be used for such a purpose and keep the content intact, so I'd recommend that you do some binary test to compare the original PDF and what you get out of the pipe.